# Appending form data to in data extension with DEManager

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am using the DEManager from marketing cloud to add the data from my external forms to my data extensions. I have a form to download different whitepapers and with a hidden field I want to send the url of the whitepaper to create a trigger. Having multiple whitepapers on my website and I only want to use one data extension for the downloads, I'm looking for a way to append the url's of the whitepapers in my data extension.

```
<form class="js-form" method="post" action="https://cl.exct.net/DEManager.aspx" name="Whitepaper_Download" novalidate>

    <legend class="h6 contact-form--ask-question__legend"></legend>

    <input name="_clientID" type="hidden" value="" />
    <input name="_deExternalKey" type="hidden" value="Whitepaper_Download" />
    <input name="_action" type="hidden" value="add" />
    <input name="_returnXML" type="hidden" value="0" />
    <input name="_successURL" type="hidden" value="" />
    <input name="_errorURL" type="hidden" value="" />

    <div class="grid-24">
        <div class="col-md-12 pre-md-0 col-sm-24">
            <div class="c-form-item">
                <input class="c-input" type="text" id="First_Name" name="First_Name" placeholder="first name" required>
                <span class="c-form-error">Please fill in your first name</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 pre-md-0 col-sm-24">
            <div class="c-form-item">
                <input class="c-input" type="text" id="Last_Name" name="Last_Name" placeholder="last name" required>
                <span class="c-form-error">Please fill in your last name</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 pre-md-0 col-sm-24">
            <div class="c-form-item">
                <input class="c-input" type="text" id="E-mail" name="E-mail" placeholder="e-mail adresse-mail address" required>
                <span class="c-form-error">Please fill in your e-mail adress</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 pre-md-0 col-sm-24">
            <div class="c-form-item">
                <input class="c-input" id="Phone" type="tel" name="Phone">
                <span class="c-form-error">Please fill in your phonenumber</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 pre-md-0 col-sm-24">
            <div class="c-form-item">
                <input class="c-input" id="Company" type="text" name="Company">
                <span class="c-form-error">Please fill in your company</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 pre-md-0 col-sm-24">
            <div class="c-form-item">
                <input class="c-input" type="hidden" id="downloadurl" name="downloadurl" value="https://....">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />


    </div>
</form>
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up the fields to capture in the data extension. Use the Name field value of those fields as defined in the data extension for the web form. (as you have done with downloadurl)

To populate the value="https://...." then it's not really a Marketing Cloud question but perhaps JavaScript or other scripting solution as to how you wish to determine what URL to populate in this value.

For example, you could use 'location.search' to return the query string and do:

```
var url = location.search;
var whitepaper= url.substring(url.indexOf('whitepaper=')+9, url.length);

$("#input").val(whitepaper);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately this isn't really what I'm looking for. I am looking for a way to add multiple values in one column, or creating a new column after a new download. I want to have an overview of all the downloads of one particular person, so for example: URL1, URL2, etc. For now I can only use the add action in the form, but this doesn't work for me. Do you think there is another solution for this?

Comment: DEManager is rather limited in functionality. 
DEManager only supports Add records, not update - make URL a Primary Field so records are unique across subscriber and URL

If you build your integration using API, then you could lookup the existing contact record, retrieve what URL Download values that exist e.g. URL1|URL2| and then Append any new download URLS e.g. URL1|URL2|URL3|URL4

With API, you could add new fields dynamically (not optimal solution). A single field with concatenated string would be better. 

Alternatively use SQL to concat your URLs from the DE to give single record